# error downloading image using php script

Tags: php, image, download, jpeg

I wrote this code to download an image from instagram. the image downloaded but it have some errors. that's mean I can download the image but I cant open it

```
<?php
  $linktopage = 'http://instagram.com/p/jTh1cBHG36/';

  $sourcecode = file_get_contents( $linktopage );

  $sourcecode = substr($sourcecode , strpos($sourcecode, 'og:image') + 19, strlen($sourcecode)); 
  $sourcecode = substr($sourcecode , 0 , strpos($sourcecode, '"'));
  $name= substr($sourcecode , strpos($sourcecode, 'com/') + 4, strlen($sourcecode));


  $fileToSend = $sourcecode;

  header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$name.'"');
  header("Content-Length: ". file_size($fileToSend));

  readfile($fileToSend);

?>
```

Comment: what exact error are you getting?

Comment: when I open the photo viewer tells me that this file can not be oped

Comment: is `$sourcecode` actually the correct, absolute URL to the image file? If you change the content-type to `text/plain` and look at what you get, is this actually binary data or an error message? or - binary data and an error message at the end or at the beginning?

Comment: $sourcecode is just HTML code.
I changed it to text/plain but it still the same error you can have a look http://im36.gulfup.com/oYlQ1.png 
I tried many photo viewers but it still the same

Comment: so, if `fileToSend` is set to `sourcecode`, and the latter is HTML code, how is `readfile` supposed to read a file?

Comment: first it is an html code then when the script run it will change to the direct url for the image  so `$fileToSend` is the url for the image

Comment: Open the image in a text editor... or simply view source.

Answer (score 0):

Comment the `Content-Length` line and it will work fine:

```
//header("Content-Length: ". file_size($fileToSend));
```

The correct function name is `filesize` (and I'm not sure if it will work on your URL).

I also see that you are missing a quote after `filename=`. It should be:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$name.'"');
```

So, the working version of your code will be:

```
  $linktopage = 'http://instagram.com/p/jTh1cBHG36/';

  $sourcecode = file_get_contents( $linktopage );

  $sourcecode = substr($sourcecode , strpos($sourcecode, 'og:image') + 19, strlen($sourcecode)); 
  $sourcecode = substr($sourcecode , 0 , strpos($sourcecode, '"'));
  $name= substr($sourcecode , strpos($sourcecode, 'com/') + 4, strlen($sourcecode));


  $fileToSend = $sourcecode;

  header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$name.'"');
  //header("Content-Length: ". filesize($fileToSend));

  readfile($fileToSend);
```

Comment: COntent-Length is overriden by apache anyway, so if you're suing the classical php+apache combo, don't ever set it.

Comment: so what should I use instead ?

Comment: What error did you get using the code from my post? It would be useful for debugging to comment the `header` lines so that you will get the output of your script in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is happening because of a typo error.

Typo error was in the following line:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$name.'"');
```

Due to the wrong name format '_' was getting added to the file extension.

One more addition in the code is for content length which is 2 line only:

```
$head = array_change_key_case(get_headers($sourcecode, TRUE));
$filesize = $head['content-length'];
```

Final Working code with typo error fixed:

```
<?php
    $linktopage = 'http://instagram.com/p/jTh1cBHG36/';
    $sourcecode = file_get_contents( $linktopage );
    $sourcecode = substr($sourcecode , strpos($sourcecode, 'og:image') + 19, strlen($sourcecode)); 
    $sourcecode = substr($sourcecode , 0 , strpos($sourcecode, '"'));
    $name= substr($sourcecode , strpos($sourcecode, 'com/') + 4, strlen($sourcecode));
    $fileToSend = $sourcecode;

    $head = array_change_key_case(get_headers($sourcecode, TRUE));
    $filesize = $head['content-length'];

    header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$name);
    header("Content-Length: ". $filesize);

    readfile($fileToSend);
?>
```